# P-group with abelian centralzer

Tags: gr.group-theory, p-groups

I will be so thankful if someone help me about the following question.
I need to know the presentation of a (if it is possible) family of finite non-abelian $p$-group $G$ with the follwing properties:
1- all non-central element have abelian centralizer.
2- $cs(G)$ has at least three integer, where by $cs(G)$ I mean the set of all conjugacy class sizes of $G$.

Comment: Is $G$ finite or not? 

Comment: Do you want such a family for each possible prime $p$, or are you happy with an infinite family for, let's say, $p=2$?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "$cs(G)$ has at least three integer".

Comment: I will be satisfied if I have a family for each $P$, However for one $p$ is also happiful for me.

Comment: Do you need $p$ to be fixed, because if not the wreath products $C_p\wr C_p$ works.


Comment: By $cs(G)$ I mean the set which contain all sizes of conjugacy classes.

Comment: @Steve: I am tempted to believe that $C_{p^n} \wr C_p$ might work in general...

Comment: I understand what $cs(G)$ means but I do not understand "has at least three integer". Do you just mean $|cs(G)| \ge 3$. If so, why not write that?

Comment: @ Professor Holt, Yes. You are right. I need $|cs(G)|>3$. 

Comment: The paper by David Rocke "p-groups with abelian centralizers" gives a full classification of the groups in question, although you will need to check which have $|cs(G)|>3$. Note that any $p$-group with abelian subgroup of index $p$ has all elements having abelian centralizers (prop 3.10.(a) of that paper) which confirms the comments of Tom and Steve regarding wreath products.

Comment: @ Nick, I have seen Rocke's paper. Actually that group has many 
relations and generators. I guess I can find more simple family of group with the above property.

Comment: @ Tom, How can I find element centralizer of $C_{p^n}\wr C_p$?

Answer (score 2):

The dihedral groups of order $2^n$ (with $n \geq 4$) form such a family.
Indeed, for such a group, we have
$$\operatorname{cs}(G) = \{ 1, 2, 2^{n-2} \} , $$
and they do have the required property that each non-central element has an abelian centralizer.

**Added.**

Here is another class of examples for arbitrary $p$, still with $\lvert\operatorname{cs}(G)\rvert = 3$ however.

Let $N$ be an arbitrary abelian $p$-group admitting a non-trivial action of $C_p$ (the cyclic group of order $p$), and let $G$ be the semidirect product
$$ G = N \rtimes C_p .$$
Then I claim that all non-central elements of $G$ have abelian centralizer, and that
$$\operatorname{cs}(G) = \{ 1, p, [N:Z(G)] \} . $$
There are three types of elements:

1. elements $g \in Z(G)$. They necessarily lie in $N$.
2. elements $g \in N \setminus Z(G)$. Such an element has conjugacy class of size at least $p$, but on the other hand these elements are of course centralized by $N$, so $C_G(g) = N$ and $\lvert g^G \rvert = p$.
3. elements $g \in G \setminus N$. Notice that for such an element, $g^p \in Z(G)$. In this case, $C_G(g) = \langle g, Z(G) \rangle$, which is an abelian group of order $p \cdot \lvert Z(G) \rvert$. Hence the conjugacy class $\lvert g^G \rvert$ has size $[N: Z(G)]$ in this case.

An example of such groups is the wreath product $C_{p^n} \wr C_p$, but of course there are many more examples of this type.

Comment: Yes, it is true. For other primes and $|cs(G)|>3$ what can we say? 

Comment: @ Tom, Thank you so much for your answer. Do you think that it is possible to construct a similar group $G$ that for $cs(G)$, we have $\{1,p^i,|N:Z(G)|\}$ for arbitrary $i$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $p$-groups of maximal class with abelian subgroup of index $p$, and order at least $p^4$ (to satisfy second condition in question)

$C_p\wr C_p$ is one such group, but order of this (these) group(s) is(are) bounded by $p$, whereas, $p$-groups of maximal class, of order $p^n$, with abelian subgroup of index $p$, exists for all $p$ and all $n\geq 3$; the book of Leedham-Green and S. McKay has an interesting example (see [link](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=34khoLiyP_QC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), Ex. 3.1.5, p. 53)